# Check if two columns are having matching values, but values are not in the same index places(Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, matching

I have two DataFrames about Super Store Sales:

- the first is named `df_orders`
- the second one is named `df_returns`

In both DataFrames we have a matching column called "Order ID", but `df_returns` has less rows than `df_orders`. What I want to do is make a new column in `df_orders` with the value 'Returned' if the Order ID is present in df_returns and 'Not returned' if not.

Here are samples of both DataFrames:

```
df_order= {'City':['Prior Lake','Chicago','NY','Prior Lake', 'Round Rock'],
           'Order ID':[86838 ,90154,15000,10000, 12447]}
df_return= {'Order ID':[90154, 86838 ],
           'Returned':['Returned', 'Returned']}

# Create DataFrame from dict
df_orders = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_order)
df_returns = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_return)
```

This is how i thought it should be checked but it is definitely not correct cause everywhere says "not returned", but I've checked manually and seen that some orders are matching. Please, help me out.

```
excel_path = r'C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\PythonFiles\Omega\SuperStoreUS.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name=None)

# 1.
df_order = df.get('Orders')
df_returns = df.get('Returns')
df_users = df.get('Users')

df_n.reset_index(drop=True)
df_returns.reset_index(drop=True)
df_n['Status'] = np.where( df_n['Order ID'].equals(df_returns['Order ID'])  and df_returns["Status"] == "Returned", "Returned", "Not returned")
```

Comment: Hello; please post in your question samples of both dataframes to help us reproduce and find the error.

Comment: Hey, I just added pictures of how they look like:)

Comment: Please post text and not pictures, so it can be copy/pasted.

Comment: need code of minimal and reproducible example for answer

Comment: https://github.com/aleksandramilicevic/superstore   Here is the dataset in excel file, I wasn't sure how else to show it, cause its having a lot of rows.

Comment: make minimal and reproducible example. we don want download your file. and don need file to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ` df_order= {'City':['Prior Lake','Chicago','NY','Prior Lake', 'Round Rock'],
           'Order ID':[86838 ,90154,15000,10000, 12447]}
df_return= {'Order ID':[90154, 86838 ],
           'Returned':['Returned', 'Returned']}

# Create DataFrame from dict
df_orders = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_order)
df_returns = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_return)`    Here is a hand written sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) :

```
df_order = pd.read_excel("SuperStoreUS.xlsx", sheet_name="Orders")
df_return = pd.read_excel("SuperStoreUS.xlsx", sheet_name="Returns")
```

Use either :

```
# --- To create a new dataframe
out = df_order.merge(df_return, on="Order ID", how="left")
out["Status"] = out["Status"].fillna("Not Returned")
```

Or:

```
# --- To update df_order
df_order = df_order.merge(df_return, on="Order ID", how="left")
df_order["Status"] = df_order["Status"].fillna("Not Returned")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a new column in df_order, with values conditioned on the row's Order ID:

```
df_orders['Status'] = df_orders['Order ID'].map(lambda x: 'Returned' if x in df_returns['Order ID'].tolist() else 'Not returned')
```